# Estou com dificuldade em formatar uma data, ela esta nesse formato Mon Jul 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso gravar a data e hora no banco, porém a data me retorna nesse formato 'Mon Jul 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000' e no banco fica '0000-00-00 00:00:00', gravei  a mesma em uma string e fica desa forma no banco '1532995200000', tentei formatar e fazer várias gambi, mas não deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Ajax que envia os dados para o PHP

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'title='+title+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&allDay='+allDay,
        url: 'agenda/acao.php',
        success: function(data){
          $('#title').val('');
        }
      });
```

> Php que recebe e grava os dados

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $_POST['start']);
$end = $_POST['end'];

try {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, start, end, teste) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);");
  $stmt->bindValue(1, $title);
  $stmt->bindValue(2, $start);
  $stmt->bindValue(3, $end);
  $stmt->bindValue(4, $start);
  $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {

}
```

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código?

Comment: Em qual banco de dados está tentando gravar, e qual o tipo de campo está utilizando para armazenar essa data?

Comment: Tente usar o `STR_TO_DATE` do mysql.

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss - Esta editado

Comment: Pedro Souza Mysql campo Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que percebi você está enviando diretamente uma variável date do javascript. Seria mais plausível formata-la antes de envia-la ao servidor.
O formato que será armazenado pelo `DateTime` do **MySQL** é `Y-m-d H:i:s` (formatação no PHP).

Então na variável `start` por exemplo que me parece uma data, antes de fazer sua requisição ajax enviando-a, utilize a seguinte função para formatar a data:

```
formatarData(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var mounth = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if (mounth < 10){
        mounth = '0' + mounth;
    }

    var day = date.getDate();
    if (day < 10){
        day = '0' + day;
    }

    var hour = date.getHours();
    if (hour < 10){
        hour = '0' + hour;
    }

    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10){
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10){
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    return year + '-' + mounth + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

var dataFormatada = formatarData(start);
```

Faça a mesma coisa com as outras datas e execute sua requisição ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'title='+title+'&start='+dataFormatada+'&end='+end+'&allDay='+allDay,
    url: 'agenda/acao.php',
    success: function(data){
      $('#title').val('');
    }
  });
```

No servidor, em seu arquivo PHP não será necessário formatar a data, simplesmente atribua a variável, pois ela já está no formato em que será armazenada no banco:

```
$start = $_POST['start'];
```